# Run an ISO file in Linux?

Tags: linux, iso-image

I have mounted an ISO file on my Linux machine. It's an ISO file to install Windows 7. It's mounted but I have no idea how to run it. There are EXE files inside, but I don't think I should touch them (even if I try I can't because they are windows EXE files). I really want to uninstall Linux because I can't update or install any new software -- or even connect to the internet. So does anyone know how to run the ISO after it is mounted?

Comment: Write iso to a DVD, then boot of disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you probably need to do is is to loopmount the iso, not burn it.

We will use sudo- which elevates accounts according to the sudoers file - i assume that its a standard ubuntu system and uses that. if doing this as root, ignore the 'sudo' in front of commands. These commands should work as the user you created during install without any additional work. All this is in terminal, so you can just copy and paste the commands with the appropriate changes.

Create a mountpoint if you haven't already (you seem to have, but lets assume you haven't)

make mountpoint by

> sudo mkdir -p /mnt/disk

mount file at /home/user/Desktop/disk1.iso to mountpoint - this uses the standard mount command

> sudo mount -o loop /home/user/Desktop/disk1.iso /mnt/disk

However you will not be able to start a windows install from linux

Comment: "However you will not be able to start a windows install from linux" -- that's what I need to do though... when I installed Linux it just worked instantly, why can I undo it just as easily? How would I uninstall Linux and install Windows instead?

Comment: Well, you installed linux off either a stripped down linux install or a live cd. Likewise windows needs to run off a windows install of some sort. Use this [howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto) to burn the iso into a cd properly. No offence, but i'm having a little trouble keeping up with your questions cause there's some seperation between what you say you want, and the end goal.

Comment: I used InfraRecorder and followed these exact instructions and it still simply opened up the ISO file on my Linux machine instead of booting the disk. But I'll try again.

Comment: wait.. what did run infracorder on? and what version of windows do you actually want to install? Also, you need try to put the disk in the system then *reboot*, go to bios, make sure the cd is the first boot device... then let it boot FROM the cd you just burnt

Comment: I ran infrarecorder on my Windows 7 machine. And I wanted to install Windows 7 with SP 1. I'll be sure to restart the computer with the disk inside, thanks!

Comment: That is incorrect answers. You can boot Win10 PRO directly from Ubuntu.

Comment: @avia while this is an old question - you could and should post your solution as its own answer then.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I will, good suggestion and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

wretrOvian's suggestion is the easiest way.

But if you don't want / can't burn the disk you can use Virtual box to help you. Windows generally doesn't support shifting from one hardware configuration to another, so you have to use the virtual machine to initiate the process and continue the rest by rebooting into the setup environment.

In pre-Vista era, windows setup has two steps -- file copying and install. Normally you get an option to copy all the installation files to a partition and run setup from there. I think you can't do this if you boot from the CD/iso, so you have to find a working Windows PE image first.

For Vista and above, the installation process seems to be simple disk imaging, so you can go through the most of the setup until the reboot after file expansion.

More elaborate steps:

1. Partition your disk and make a PRIMARY NTFS partition that is big enough (10G+ for pre-Vista, 25GB+ otherwise) and set the "boot" (active) flag to it.
2. Follow [this](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#rawdisk) guide to create a vmdk file for that NTFS partition. (Do not use the whole drive because Windows will overwrite the Linux boot loader.)
3. Setup the VM. Make sure your VM configuration (number of CPUs, chipset and disk controller) is similar to the real hardware. Otherwise you may get a BSoD when you reboot the host computer to continue the installation process.
4. (Pre-Vista) Boot from a PE disk, run the setup.exe on the CD and choose to copy all the installation files to disk. (It's hidden behind a button on the page where you choose system language and components.)
5. When the setup program automatically reboots, turn off the virtual machine at the POST screen.
6. Add an entry to your Linux boot loader to boot from the NTFS partition. For older Grub, it's a simple `root` command and `chainloader +1`. There're plenty of guides online.
7. Reboot your Linux and choose the Windows partition in the boot menu.

Comment: The problem is I can't install software or anything. And I want to completely overwrite linux.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is - burn the ISO to a Disc using a iso-burning software (not as a file).
Then boot with the disc to run the Windows setup.
(this is assuming the iso is bootable)

**EDIT -** 
An ISO is like a zip (compressed file) - it may contain multiple files and directories. And it also contains boot information that is meant for the boot sector of your disc. Hence, you don't burn the file itself. You also don't burn the contents of the iso file by themselves. What you need to find is a burning software that supports creating discs FROM an ISO file. I hope this helps.

Comment: I used InfraRecorder and used the option to "write the contents of a disc-image (iso) to a CD". I also tried the native software that Windows 7 has but I got a stream-write error.

Answer (score 0):

Use an external thumb drive. Copy the iso to it. Leave it in your computer and boot to it. You may have to hit F2 during boot to change the boot order so that your computer will boot to the drive. The UEFI will display a message as it boots to tell you about the option. Detailed instructions follow:

To copy the iso to the thumb drive, you first need to know the location of the thumb drive. Insert the thumb drive then execute

```bash
lsblk
```

to list all block devices. The thumb drive will be sdb or some other letter after the sd. Linux will assign sda, sdb, sdc... to every SATA device it finds. The thumb drive you just inserted should be the last one listed. The thumb drive might already be partitioned creating sdb1, sdb2..., but don't worry about that. The entire thumb drive will be COMPLETELY OVERWRITTEN, so make sure there is nothing on it that you want.

After determining the location of the thumb drive, its file name (everything is a file in linux), is /dev/sdb (still using sdb as an example). Make SURE you have located the correct drive. Copying the iso to the drive will erase all of it. Then replace the contents of the thumb drive with the iso:

```
sudo cp /dev/sdLETTER WINDOWS_INSTALL_IMAGE.iso
```

Linux will ask your password and a short bit later the thumb drive will contain an exact copy the iso ready to boot. You can look at it with `lsblk`. Reboot to the thumb drive. After you install windows overwriting your entire hard drive, reboot as you say goodbye to the best OS ever made.